# Max/Min value of Dictionary of List

Tags: python

I have a dictionary mapping an id_ to a list of data values like so: `dic = {id_ : [v1, v2, v3, v4]}`.
I'm trying to iterate through every value in the dictionary and retrieve the max/min of a certain index of the list mappings.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
maximum = max([data[0], ??) for id_, data in self.dic.items()])
```

...but obviously this will not work. Is it possible to do this in one line as above?

Comment: Can you show some more elements in your dict?

Comment: "retrieve the max/min"? What do you expect the result to look like?

Comment: Sure, given a dictionary like this: `dictA = { 1 : [22, 31, 14], 2 : [9, 4, 3], 3 : [77, 15, 23]}`... running my 'imaginary' func on data[0] would return 77.

Comment: We can presume that the lists are fixed lengths.

Comment: Yes, in this particular case the lists are all length 4 and will not change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use it something like this:

```
maximum = max(data[0] for data in dic.values())
```

since you are not using your `keys`, simply use `dict.values()` to get just the values.

Comment: Will this iterate through every value of index 0 in the dict and return the max? I don't see how. `dic.values()` will return a list of lists `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`

Comment: @Clever. dict.values() returns a list of all the values in the dict. You can try printing out it and see what you get. And yes this will give maimum of data[0] out of all values.

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to be working. Printing out the .values() does return a list of lists, but the maximum is certainly higher than my output. Just glazing over it I can see a val[0] at 70,000 wheras the max is returning 9936.

Comment: @Clever: do your values happen to be strings and not integers or floats?

Comment: @Clever. What input are you giving?

Comment: I'm a class-A dumbass. Maybe I should take a break for the rest of the day.

Comment: @Clever. So you found the issue? And what was it?

Comment: I'm scanning a website and reading the strings into a dictionary. I failed to convert the data into floats after `data = line.split()`

Comment: @Clever. Ok. Well, it happens sometimes.

Comment: is there a way to get the key of the maximum value in the list?

Answer (score 1):

Using a [*generator expression*](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and [**`max()`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

```
In [10]: index = 0

In [11]: dictA = { 1 : [22, 31, 14], 2 : [9, 4, 3], 3 : [77, 15, 23]}

In [12]: max(l[index] for l in dictA.itervalues())
Out[12]: 77
```

Note: [`itervalues()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) returns an [*iterator*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) over the dictionary’s values without making a *copy*, and is therefore more efficient than [`values()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) (in Python < 3).

Comment: Is there a significant difference between .itervalues() and .values()? Would it be that .values() returns an entire list while .itervalues() is more conservative with space?

Comment: @Clever: I was updating my answer while you typed that with an explanation.